# Statically initializing array inside struct upon struct initialization

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

I am trying to build a ring buffer by using statically allocated array (requirement, already built dinamical, later decided to go statical). However, I would like to have a generic ring buffer structure that would enable instantiating different sizes of arrays inside of it. 
I have this structure:

```
typedef struct measurementsRingBuffer
{   
    int maxSize;
    int currentSize;
    double measurementsArray[MEAS_ARRAY_CAPACITY];
} measurementsRingBuffer;
```

I instantiate the structure by:

```
measurementsRingBuffer buffer = { .maxSize = MEAS_ARRAY_CAPACITY, .currentSize = 0 };
```

Is there any way I could define array size upon struct instantiation, instead of defining it in structure itself?
I does not sound possible, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: With static storage duration?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you use a pointer instead of an array, and if the array is the last member of your structure, then I guess you can decide of its size when you allocate the memory. Anyway instead of having sizeof(measurementsRingBuffer) you will have the cumulated size of all the members plus n*sizeof(double) with n the size of your array

Comment: It is real-time system with strict memory consumption requirements. It needs to know how much memory will be needed.

Comment: If the array is defined before the structure is defined, you could simply use `sizeof(the_array)` as array size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a pointer to an array:

```
typedef struct measurementsRingBuffer
{   
    int maxSize;
    int currentSize;
    double* measurementsArray ;
} measurementsRingBuffer;

double small_array[10];
measurementsRingBuffer small = { .maxSize = 10 , .measurementsArray = small_array } ;
```

or even a compound literal:

```
measurementsRingBuffer small = { .maxSize = 10 , .measurementsArray = ( double[10] ){ 0 } } ;
```

Note that the if compound literal is defined outside of a body of a function, it has static storage duration.

Comment: Nice! This sounds correct, gonna try it. Thanks a lot!